# Can the google map API return a street address that was clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to work out an app design in my head and I would like the user to be able to click there destination address on the map of there area.

If I know the user is in Liverpool is it possible to pop up the map over liverpool and then allow the user to select on the map where they wanna go, and the google map/api return the street or the name of the area?

I've never used googlemap/api yet so just wondering if this kind of thing is possible on the iphone yet.

Many Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since iOS 3.0 it's possible to use the [MKReverseGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKReverseGeocoder) Class provided by the MapKit.